# Button that changes form field value based on other field values (D8)

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I made a simple form with two input fields and a button. The button is supposed to enter the sum of the two input fields in a third field. I want the value in the third field to be editable by the user. 
I've tried to change the default_value with an ajax callback, but that doesn't work. I can change all other field properties though (description, placeholder, title, ...), but not default_value.
I also tried changing the value through form_state -> setValue() in a custom validate function that I attached to the button. But form_state seems to be reset to the initial value upon form rebuild.

This is my code:

```
  class calculatorForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'calculator_example';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="calculator-form-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['number1'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#weight' => 0,
      '#title' => $this->t('number 1'),
    );

    $form['number2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#weight' => 1,
      '#title' => $this->t('number 2'),
    );

    $form['button_sum'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#name' => 'sum',
      '#value' => t('+'),
      '#weight' => 2,
    );

    $form['sum'] = array(
      '#title' => $this->t('sum'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#weight' => 3,
    );

    // attempt with validation function
    $form['button_sum']['#element_validate'] = array([$this,'calculator_example_custom_validate']);

    // attempt with ajax callback
    $form['button_sum']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => [$this,'sumValues_ajax_callback'], //'sumValues_ajax_callback',
      'event' => 'click',
      'wrapper' => 'calculator-form-wrapper',
      );

    $form['sum']['#description'] = t('calculated sum');
    return $form;
  }


  function sumValues_ajax_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)  {
    $n1 = $form_state->getValue('number1');
    $n2 = $form_state->getValue('number2');
    $sum = $n1 + $n2;
    $form['sum']['#placeholder'] = $sum;
    $form['sum']['#default_value'] = $sum;
    return $form;
  }

  function calculator_example_custom_validate($element, &$form_state, $form) {
    $n1 = $form_state->getValue('number1');
    $n2 = $form_state->getValue('number2');
    $sum = $n1 + $n2;
    $form_state->setValue('sum' , $sum);
    drupal_set_message($this-> t('sum is '). $sum);
    $form_state->setRebuild('true');
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {  }

}
```

Does anyone know why $sum doesn't appear as a value in the 'sum' field? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: There is documentation on this at [AJAX Forms](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. In case someone else stumbles upon this: In the ajax callback you need to change #value instead of #default_value.

So this callback works:

```
function sumValues_ajax_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)  {
   $n1 = $form_state->getValue('number1');
   $n2 = $form_state->getValue('number2');
   $sum = $n1 + $n2;
   $form['sum']['#placeholder'] = $sum;
   $form['sum']['#value'] = $sum;
   return $form;
}
```